# Find option select not show in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to show specific state in 2nd select when i select city in 1st select.
Next code work in firefox, but in chrome not show state option.

I think I need to change `city.find("option[value=" + self + "]").show();` but what?

```
  var city = jQuery("#city");
    jQuery("#state").on("change", function () {
        var self = jQuery(this).val();

        if (jQuery("#state").val() == "0") {
            jQuery(".city").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(".city").show();
        }
        city.find("option").hide();
        city.find("option[value=" + self + "]").show();
        city.find("option[value=" + 0 + "]").prop("selected", true);
    }).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your value in quotes `' '`:

```
city.find("option[value='" + self + "']").show();
// -------------------- ^  and here  ^ ---------
```